# UITableViewController disappears after asynchronous query

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Hoping you can help me out...I've been trying to figure this issue out for a couple days now.

I'm using Parse (www.parse.com) as my backend, and have hosted it on my own AWS server.

**Structure of the app**:
In AppDelegate, if user is logged in, show a ViewController that sets up my SlideMenuControllerSwift (https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) and my TabBarController. 
[Storyboard][1]

In my tab bar controller, I have a navigation controller that leads to a UITableViewController that segues to another UITableViewController when I click on a row.

**Problem**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuXrM.jpg

1) I click on a row and it performs an asynch query to my parse database

2) The data populates the table and then disappears

3) If I change the tab and go back to the main tab, the data reappears

Also

1) I click on a row and it performs an asynch query to my parse database

2) The data populates the table and then disappears

3) If I go back to the original UITableViewController, it does not transition back properly, and I need to change tabs back and forth until it reappears

**Code:**

I segue to the documents table view controller using the storyboard segue. Here is the relevant code in my DocumentsTableViewController:

```
class DocumentTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MMCropDelegate {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    print("initDocs")
}

var specificDocs=[Document](){
    didSet{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //we might be called from the parse block which executes in seperate thread
            self.loadView()
        })
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    print("we loadeD")
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Job Documents"

    let cameraButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Camera"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.didPressCamera(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cameraButton

    self.queryForTable()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
func queryForTable() {
    // Run a spinner to show a task in progress
    let progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    progressHUD.label.text = "Loading..."

    //2 using those jobActions to find which documents are mine
    let query = PFQuery(className: Document.parseClassName())
    query.whereKey(Document.jobActionCol(), containedIn: jobActions)
    query.includeKey(Document.documentCategoryCol())
//        do {
//            let test = try query.findObjects()
//            self.specificDocs = test as! [Document]
//            progressHUD.hideAnimated(true)
//        } catch {
//            print("error!")
//        }
// FIND WHY THIS DOESNT WORK....WHAT THE F
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                self.specificDocs = objects as! [Document]
                print("done")
                progressHUD.hideAnimated(true)

            } else {
               // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return specificDocs.count

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier")
        if ((cell) == nil){
            cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
        }

        cell!.textLabel?.text = specificDocs[indexPath.row].documentCategory!.type!
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
//        print(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.performSelector("recursiveDescription"))
        return cell!
    }


    deinit {
        print("docs deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I couldn't put this in the original post. Here is a screenshot of my storyboard:http://imgur.com/Hntac8L

Comment: Do you call `tableView.reloadData()` somewhere in a background-thread?

Comment: Nope, only call loadView on the main thread when specifiedDocs is updated, and when call reloadData() in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, now I see intention of your codes. But, Do you have some reason that doing? It isn't right way that directly call loadView().

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

move to first in viewWillAppear and, It will be work except too fast done to receive from parse.

> Normal way will be like below:

```
var specificDocs=[Document](){
didSet{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        //we might be called from the parse block which executes in seperate thread
        self.loadView()
    })
}
```

> self.loadView() to self.tableView.reloadData().

`tableView.dataSource = self`
`tableView.delegate = self`

> That doesn't needs.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.tableView.reloadData()}
```

> That doesn't needs too.

**Anyway, your codes will work just modify calling self.loadView() to self.tableView.reloadData()**

Comment: Thank you Jay Choi! I can't believe such a silly thing was causing me so many headaches... I was debugging way more things than I needed.